# Routing url's in a single page on the front end

Tags: ajax, vue.js, frontend

Here is what I would like to recreate:
https://www.crytek.com/games

The single page has a list of games that when clicked it updates the jumbotron but more interesting is that it also reroutes the url. The very url is fully functional and can be visited directly,bookmarked, run SEO, etc. Can anyone identify what technology is being used to achieve this dynamic single page and how it is done? (I would prefer to use Vue.js if possible). I can't figure out if this is with a front end framework or on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called routing, many JS frameworks have their own. If they don't there's usually 3rd party modules that can handle it. For Vue check out https://router.vuejs.org/